# Using default cursor when hovering over text. Is it okay?

Tags: css, cursor

So this is maybe a bit of an OCD question. When hovering over text in a webpage the mouse cursor changes to the I beam. I hate that! So I will use CSS to use the default cursor on all elements that aren't links.

Is there any issues in doing this? Am I screwing up any accessibility or something else?

I think it makes it a bit nicer to look at the page with your mouse moving all over without it constantly changing shape on you. I also think it helps make the links stand out more as when the cursor does change, its for a link.

Thanks!

Comment: No messing with accessibility, but quite annoying for HCI. Users generally expect that behaviour, so why avoid it?

Comment: Change the cursor in your browser if you don't like how the rest of the world does it. Changing it for everyone else will just be annoying.

Comment: +1 @kainaw! That's a user's decision, not yours ;)

Comment: I support kainaw.  You can setup your browser to change it for all websites for you if you care.  Don't touch my curser!

Comment: Strong opinions here :) I think I won't do this anymore! @BenM what's HCI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change that you are making is completely visual and won't affect the "accessibility" of the site...but you might piss people off the same way people get pissed about target="_blank".

Comment: Thanks! Based on your reply and all the comments above (that came very quickly), this is more of a hot topic than I had expected! :) Guess people feel strongly about seeing that stupid I beam. I'll stay away from that from now on.